# Need help making a "compliment generator"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simple compliment generator that takes a noun and an adjective from two separate list ands randomly combines them together. I can get one on its own to work but trying to get the second word to appear makes weird stuff happen. What am I doing wrong here? any input would be great.

```
import random
sentence = "Thou art a *adj *noun."
sentence = sentence.split()
adjectives = ["decadent", "smelly", "delightful", "volatile", "marvelous"]
indexCount= 0
noun = ["dandy", "peaseant", "mule", "maiden", "sir"]
wordCount= 0
for word in sentence:
    if word =="*adj":
        wordChoice = random.choice (adjectives)
        sentence [indexCount] = wordChoice
    indexCount += 1

for word in sentence:
     if "*noun" in word:
        wordChoice = random.choice (noun)
        sentence [wordCount] = wordChoice
     wordCount += 1
st =""
for word in sentence:
    st+= word + " "
print (st)
```

The end result nets me a double noun. how would I get rid of the duplicate?

Comment: What are the weird stuff?

Comment: I get an undesired result for my print statement: maiden art a delightful *noun.

Comment: So, just to mention, basically all of this code could be replaced with `st = "Thou art a {} {}".format(random.choice(adjectives), random.choice(noun))`. You've managed to write more lines in Python than it would take to implement this in C.

Comment: That would be a huge time saver, but due to this being an assignment I have to implement all of the current code to meet the requirements.

Comment: The assignment says "do this the most roundabout way possible"? Even for a poor solution, `"Thou are an *adj *noun".replace("*adj", random.choice(adjectives)).replace("*noun", random.choice(noun))` would be less ridiculous.

Comment: Yes. I'm guessing is "do the long way" followed by a "by the way here's the short way" after turning it in.

Comment: I ran your code, and the result is what you expect. -> close as cannot reproduce.

Comment: thanks for all the help I saw the last error was just me checking with a 'print (wordChoice)' at the end... entirely my fault.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't incrementing `wordCount` in the second loop as you do `indexCount` in the first.

Comment: I went ahead an made the changes but I get the same loss of order for the result

Comment: Check your indentation.

Comment: I'm getting closer but still getting the same result.

Comment: Your code as posted has syntax errors.  Your second loop should look VERY much like your first.

Comment: Lastly i'm getting a duplicate noun. is there a way to remove this?

Comment: How many times do I have to say your second loop has to look like your first?